# Problems with code node autocomplete in vsc

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

So I'm using vsc to write node.js, but vsc doesn't give me the methods when I press . as in the image, I've reinstalled VSC deleting every extension that I had, and nothing, using just node extensions and nope, I kinda don't  understand the `npm install @type/node` solution, which I did and yet  nothing happened

[image: this is how it looks when I'm coding]

Comment: check whether you have `Visual Studio IntelliCode` installed

Comment: @RohitAmbre yes, it is installed, it doesn't have any problems with another languajes.